# When using torch.autocast, how do I force individual layers to float32

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

I'm trying to train a model in mixed precision. However, I want a few of the layers to be in full precision for stability reasons. How do I force an individual layer to be float32 when using `torch.autocast`? In particular, I'd like for this to be onnx compileable.

Is it something like:

```py
with torch.autocast(device_type='cuda', enabled=False, dtype=torch.float16):
    out = my_unstable_layer(inputs.float())
```

Edit:

Looks like this is indeed the official method. See the [torch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html#autocast-and-custom-autograd-functions).

Answer (score 4):

I think the motivation of [torch.autocast](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html) is to automate the reduction of precision (not the increase).

If you have [functions that need a particular `dtype`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html#functions-that-need-a-particular-dtype), you should consider using, [custom_fwd](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html#torch.cuda.amp.custom_fwd)

```py
import torch
@torch.cuda.amp.custom_fwd(cast_inputs=torch.complex128)
def get_custom(x):
    print('  Decorated function received', x.dtype)
def regular_func(x):
    print('  Regular function received', x.dtype)
    get_custom(x)

x = torch.tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.half, device='cuda')
with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(False):
    print('autocast disabled')
    regular_func(x)
with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(True):
    print('autocast enabled')
    regular_func(x)
```

```txt
autocast disabled
  Regular function received torch.float16
  Decorated function received torch.float16
autocast enabled
  Regular function received torch.float16
  Decorated function received torch.complex128
```

### Edit: Using torchscript

I am not sure how much you can rely on this, due to a comment in the documentation. However the comment is apparently outdated.

Here is an example where I trace the model with autocast enabled, feeze it and then I use it and the value is indeed cast to the specified type

```py
class Cast(torch.nn.Module):    
    @torch.cuda.amp.custom_fwd(cast_inputs=torch.float64)
    def forward(self, x):
        return x

with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(True):
    model = torch.jit.trace(Cast().eval(), x)
model = torch.jit.freeze(model)

x = torch.tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.half, device='cuda')
print(model(x).dtype)
```

```txt
torch.float64
```

But I suggest you to validate this approach before using it for a serious application.

Comment: Do you know if this will work with torchscript?

Comment: Not sure, maybe [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html#:~:text=For%20now%2C%20we%20suggest%20to%20disable%20the%20Jit%20Autocast%20Pass) means that don't.

Comment: When I use the approach I listed in my question above, it does appear to work in torch. It's just in torchscript that it fails. So I don't think the decorator is needed

Comment: Check the example I appended to the answer. Does it help?